# Pandoc fails to render markdown with image: "! Missing endcsname inserted."

Tags: macos, markdown, pandoc, cross-reference

I am having trouble rendering a .md-file with since I inserted an image. Before everything worked quite well.

### My configuration

- MacBook Air / MacOS 12.5
- multiple markdown files for each chapter: 1_einleitung.md / 2_theorie.md / ...

  - there is a short yaml-block that references the bibliography file within the same folder: *bib.bib*.
  - I use a special LUA filter (*pangb4e*) for numbered examples and interlinear glossing
- a metadata.yml ➞ find the yaml code below.
- a Make-file ➞ find the makefile code below
- the image is stored in images/danes1.png (I even tried to use the entire path instead of the relative one)

#### 2_theorie.md

```
---
bibliography: [bib.bib]
---

[...]

![Die einfache lineare Progression](images/danes1.png){width=300px #fig:danes1}
```

#### metadata.yml

```
---
author: ...
affiliation: ...
title: ...
date: \today
# number-sections: true
# abstract: This is the abstract.

# Formatting
bibliography: [bib.bib]
cls: linguistics-and-education.csl
lang: de-DE
link-citations: true
linkReferences: true
nameInLink: true 
fontsize: 12pt
papersize: a4
indent: true
fontfamily: sourcesanspro
fontfamilyoptions: default
geometry: margin=2.5cm
linestretch: 1.5
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{gb4e}
    - \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}


figureTitle: "Abbildung"
tableTitle: "Tabelle"
figPrefix:
  - "Fig."
  - "Figs."
tblPrefix:
  - "Tab."
secPrefix:
  - Kapitel
loftitle: "# Abbildungsverzeichnis"
lottitle: "# Tabellenverzeichnis"
...
```

#### makefile

```
1_einleitung:
    pandoc 1_einleitung.md -o 1_einleitung.pdf \
    --metadata-file=metadata.yml \
    --number-sections \
    --strip-comments \
    --filter pandoc-crossref \
    --citeproc \
    --lua-filter addons/pangb4e.lua \
    

2_theorie:
    pandoc 2_theorie.md -o 2_theorie.pdf \
    --metadata-file=metadata.yml \
    --number-sections \
    --strip-comments \
    --filter pandoc-crossref \
    --citeproc \
    --lua-filter addons/pangb4e.lua \
```

### The error output

Currently, I do my writing within the *2_theorie.md* and run the command `make 2_theorie` to produce a pdf. I just inserted an image in *2_theorie.md* and a get the following error:

```
san@MacBook-Air Doktorarbeit % make 2_theorie
pandoc 2_theorie.md -o 2_theorie.pdf \
    --metadata-file=metadata.yml \
    --number-sections \
    --strip-comments \
    --filter pandoc-crossref \
    --citeproc \
    --lua-filter addons/pangb4e.lua \

Error producing PDF.
! Missing endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   let 
l.591 }
```

When I delete the image, the code runs as usual but I need to be able to use images in my work.

If you need more information, please let me know!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem myself here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448314/not-able-to-use-images-if-i-call-gb4e-sty

The problem was the package *gb4e*. I disabled the a feature of the package right after loading it and panda worked just fine

### Edits in the metadata.yml

```
[...]
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{gb4e}
    - \noautomath # <-- I added this line the to metadata.yml
[...]
```